# problems during object release

Tags: objective-c, object, release-management

I have some problems during when and which object to be release

You can say my knowledge towards this is less

i have following conditions please suggest me the answer accordingly

- situation-1

NSMutableString *str=[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Hello World!"];
NSMutableArray *array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
[array addObject:str];

Now when i tried to release str then usage of array affected in future...and Vice Versa
Tell me can i release both?

- situation-2

NSMutableString *str=[[NSMutableString alloc]init]; 
str=@"Hello World !";
str=[self getData];           //calling a method which returns a string
[str release];

I think i am creating a memory leak here(how to solve it?)

please clear these situations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first situation, you'll need to call `[str release];` after adding it to the array, like this:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello World!"];
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[array addObject:str];
[str release];
```

This way, `array` holds the only retain call on the string. Once you release `array` later, you won't have any memory leak issues.

I'm a little confused about the second situation. `str` here is a pointer. You seem to be assigning three different objects to to same pointer:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //first object
str=@"Hello World !"; //second object
str=[self getData]; //third object
```

by the time you call `[str release]`, you've created a memory leak because you've lost the first mutable string. The second time you called `str =`, you lost any way to access that first `NSMutableString`.

Assuming that you're looking to concatenate all of these (since you chose NSMutableString), you might try this:

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; //first object
[str appendString:@"Hello World!"];
[str appendString:[self getData]];
[str release];
```

If the `[self getData]` method returns an autoreleased string, you'll be fine. If `getData` returns a retained string (if you used `alloc` and `init`), you'll need to assign it to an intermediate pointer and release it after adding it to `str`.

Comment: You means there is no problem with my second case(if i return an  autorelease string)?

Comment: no, your second case still has problems, since you're reassigning `str` two extra times. When you use `str=@HelloWorld!"`, that first object you initialized gets lost. My answer changes your assignments to calls to `appendString`.

Comment: +1---  
I have read that if we have 2 strings (both are initialized)
  
and if  i use  
Str1=Str2;

then you have to release only one of them?(please correct me if wrong)

Comment: if we talk about IBoutlets..Should i release them?

Comment: You might need to read up on pointers. This is correct, but that's because Str1 isn't the actual string, it's a pointer to the string. If you use Str1 = Str2, that means you have two pointers to the same string, so you only call release once. In your example, you have one pointer for two strings, so one of the strings gets lost.

Comment: Yes, for releasing outlets. If I answered your question here, would you mind marking it completed?

Comment: yes, if you declare an IBOutlet, you need to release it in your class's dealloc method. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What is the need of creating the NSMutableString  You can directly use NSString for this purpose